# code for add the search box in the html site without using google custom search?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi everyone I have an site full of  html.I need to add the search box in that site,I searched the go ogle ! most of them searched results yields to the go ogle custom search .I need the search box which has search my html site and show the results in my html site itself .

Thanks and anyone much appreciated

Comment: I need search box without using the google custom search ?? I have an html site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching does not work as simply as you are making it seem.

To implement a search feature, you'll need to index all your pages on your server, then use some sort of server-side code to process queries and return search results.

I recommend you learn PHP and MySQL as these will be essential in what i understand you are trying to do.

Hope i helped.

Comment: what about if its client side since i think it is `<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var foundin = $('*:contains(" this is a page")');
});`
</script>

Comment: That'll only search through the current page's html. By what i understand he wants to search through multiple pages...